# SUMIF Array Formula with "GREATER THAN"

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, sum, array-formulas

I know this may work:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(SUMIF(D2:D9&F2:F9,J2:J3&H2,E2:E9)))
```

But I don't know how to find any solution for this

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(SUMIF(D2:D9&F2:F9,J2:J3&(">"&H2),E2:E9)))
```

Basically, I want to SUMIF with multiple criterias with array formula. But I can't find a way with criteria that greater than something

this is the sample case: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lyPSurAudZOAn2HHGPaKcgmwso46f3K4dVYA6dwlDjM/edit#gid=0

the case is about summing the quantity given from each activity, given some range of date.

1. array formula is needed since I want the list of activity to be flexibly added, without me having to edit the formula.
2. as far as I know, sumifs cant be used because sumifs doesn't work with array formula

Comment: Have you considered SUMIFS()?

Comment: You do not need array formula while `SUMIFS()` can handle multiple criteria. Show us your sample data so that we can help you.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lyPSurAudZOAn2HHGPaKcgmwso46f3K4dVYA6dwlDjM/edit?usp=sharing

that is the link.

actually yes, i know SUMIFS. but i need sumif because in my case, i need to use array formula. 

The point is, is there any way for me to use SUMIF array formula with "greater than" criteria??

I want to sum the quantity of my activity (with activity as criteria in a collection of ranges), that is greater than given date.

The actual case can be seen in the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF((F2:F>H2)*(REGEXMATCH(D2:D, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, J2:J))), E2:E, )))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

or try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(E2:E, REGEXMATCH(D2:D, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, J:J)), F2:F>H2))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Some alternative:

sumif and vlookup==>

```
=arrayformula(sumif((1-isna(vlookup(D2:D9,J2:J3,1)))*F2:F9,">" & H2,E2:E9))
```

sum if and vlookup:

```
=arrayformula(sum(if((1-isna(vlookup(D2:D9,J2:J3,1)))*F2:F9>H2,E2:E9,0)))
```

Sum and vlookup:

```
=arrayformula(sum((iferror(vlookup(D2:D9,J2:J3,1),"")=D2:D9)*(F2:F9>H2)*E2:E9))
```